dbeaver doesn't show my docker postgres databases and its content
When I connect via psql with this command docker exec -it 4e18793cb23c psql -U postgres mytestdb, I can see my database and work with it. But when I connect with dbeaver to my postgres docker container, it doesn't show me my data. But when I want to create the same database it says that it exists. Also, doing a select on the tables, it says that the table doesn't exist.
Few things that I checked are:

the directory (zorin os/ubuntu) /var/lib/postgres doesn't exist
Inspect docker volume shows me this:

docker volume inspect pgdata                                                                                                                                           
    [
    {

        "CreatedAt": "2024-04-13T09:03:53+02:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/pgdata/_data",
        "Name": "pgdata",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }]

I don't have Postgres directly on my machine installed.
How do I make my databases and tables and everything appear in dbeaver?

SOLUTION: this is crazy, but checking the "show all databases" in the connection settings solved this issue.

Not sure how you are launching the PostgreSQL container, but that is likely to be the key.
Docker Client
If you are launching PostgreSQL using the Docker client then you'd do something like this:
docker run --rm -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password \
    --name postgres postgres:latest

You mention that you are starting your container with docker start but I presume that this means that at some stage you would have kicked it off with docker run.
IMHO the Docker Compose route to launching the database is better because it documents all the details associated with launching the container.
Docker Compose
If you are using Docker Compose then something like this:
 docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./create-table.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-table.sql:ro
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password

The ports will ensure that the database is accessible from outside of the Docker network.
There are two volume mounts: (1) for an initialisation script and (2) for persisting the database between sessions.
In screenshot below you can see the Docker Compose stack running (top terminal panel), a connection using docker exec on that container (bottom terminal panel) and a connection from DBeaver.


I am not using docker compose. I either start it with the command in my question or with docker start [containername], as shown in the postgres docker hub manual or as seen in some youtube videos.

sorry. a clarification. the first command in my question is how I access psql in my terminal, after I start the docker with doccker start
